# I get an error when using {future} and {furrr} functions within a Golem Shiny App, what does it come from?

Tags: r, shiny, r-future, furrr, golem

I am currently working on a Golem Shiny App called "package_name" (which is a requirement for me) for which some functions I created need to use functions from the `{furrr}` and `{future}` packages.
However, whenever I try to run them, I get the following error :

> Error : there is no package called 'package_name'

Please note that whenever any function that does not use either package works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what the problem might be ?

Thanks !

Comment: With parallel codes, you may have to import the packages, objects etc.  Without an example code, it is not clear though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building the application with `{golem}`, the package with the app is not installed on your machine.
When you use `{future}`, the code is run inside **another R session**, meaning that the objects are transported and the libraries reloaded.

BUT if you try to use a function from inside your current app into your future, you need to make it "transportable", and using `package_name::function()` will not work because your package is not installed.

Let's say you need to use `current_app_fun()`, defined inside your package.
Technically, `{future}` will be able to transport this function, as it uses `{globals}` to identify the objects to transport to the new R session.

```r
observeEvent( input$bla , {
  # future() will identify that it needs to
  # transport current_app_fun()
  future({
    current_app_fun()
  })
})
```

You can also do an extra step just to be extra cautious:

```r
observeEvent( input$bla , {
  func_for_future <- current_app_fun
  future({
    func_for_future()
  })
})
```

Cheers,
Colin

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very clear indeed, and it does perfectly solve my issue !

Comment: @HenriFreixe Great! Feel free to accept the answer then :)

Comment: @ColinFAY this was a great and very elegant solution...cheers!

Comment: @ColinFAY thanks for this solution (and for golem!). One issue I have with this solution, however, is that it is cumbersome if you have custom functions that depend on other custom functions. Transporting all of them can be tedious (e.g., I have a data ingestion function that depends on ~7 other utility functions.) Is there a plan to make custom functions in `golem` automatically transportable when using `future` and `promises`? Or perhaps this is not a `golem` issue and cannot be addressed there.