# Using future for async in an R package - cannot find custom functions

Tags: r, r-package, r-future

I have an R package and I want to use `future` to run stuff asynchronously. `future` is not able to find the functions in my package. This is a known [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502816/i-get-an-error-when-using-future-and-furrr-functions-within-a-golem-shiny-ap/68540678#comment134301547_68540678) in the context of `golem` apps. I know there is a work-around that involves assigning the functions to the environment in future (see the linked issue), but I'm hoping someone can help me with a function or improvement that will help `future` find *all* functions in my package.

Here's a simplified test package illustrating the problem:

My package `testpkg` has this file structure:

```
testpkg/
├── DESCRIPTION
├── NAMESPACE
├── R
│   └── do_stuff.R
├── man
│   └── do_stuff.Rd
└── testpkg.Rproj
```

`do_stuff.R` is defined as follows:

```
#' A function that clearly does stuff
#' @export
do_stuff <- function() {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  "Done"
}
```

Now in an interactive script I try the following:

```
devtools::load_all()
library(future)
plan(multisession)

val %<-% do_stuff()
val
```

And the console reads `Error: there is no package called ‘testpkg’`

Like I said, I know there are workarounds, but in my actual use case I have many functions some of which depend on other custom functions, so it becomes very loopy to assign each and every one of those functions (not to mention data objects). I'd like a way for `future` to see all functions in my package.

Comment: Have you tried building and installing your package?

Comment: Seems that building and installing it does address the problem. I wonder how this will work in the context of `golem` apps where conventionally you don't build the package. I suppose there's nothing stopping from building the package prior to running the app. Thanks!

Comment: This is because `load_all` only loads in the current environment.